# run .py with option over files in folder in python

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that I run over a text file using the following on mac terminal:

```
python texter.py --text file.txt
```

I want to iterate the script over a folder of text files, I run the following on mac termianl:

```
bash for f in ~/directory; do python texter.py --text $file done;
```

However, I get the following error:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

does the second line of code missing something? or is there any other better way of itterating over files in folder?

Comment: `for file in ~/directory; do python texter.py --text $file; done`  (note the `;` before `done`)

Comment: @cdarke has just done that but it gives the same error.

Comment: also note `file` and `$file` (no `f`)

Comment: error is likely because of starting `bash`... remove that... in addition to suggestions in previous comments

Comment: also, you'd likely need `~/directory/*`

Comment: @sundeep yes those changes worked well! removing bash, the `*`, and the `;` of @cdarke. I worked with either `file` or `f` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the answers in the comments

- You need to dir/* if you want to loop though the files
- you will need to add semicolons ; in the right places if you want to make it a single line command

so

```
for file in ~/directory/* ; do python texter.py --text $file; done
```

would be the same as

```
for file in ~/directory/* 
do 
   python texter.py --text $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
for file in ~/directory/ do python texter.py --text $file; done (note the ; before done)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.